# xna fires OutOfMemoryException on 1.3GB

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xna, xna-4.0

so I am currently developping a game in XNA studio and bumped into the following problem:

whenever I use more than 1.3GB of RAM, an OutOfMemoryException is fired, after googling this I found out this is because of a rule in the .NET 4.5 framework which limits the memory usage for 32 bit applications. It could be solved by changing the compiled bin with EditBin.exe that shipped with visual studio.

because XNA does not support 64 bit compiling as it has been dicontinued, I was wondering if there is a way where I can guarantee the memory limit is increased to 4GB (or even 3GB) when I compile it for the end user? I was told there are /LARGEADDRESSAWARE options but I don't really know how to use them in a XNA project.

Comment: Maybe switching across to Monogame (which has an almost identical API) might offer a solution?

Comment: just tried the same with Monogame, it gave me the same issue